# WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE messages get lost when reading RAWINPUT via GetRawInputBuffer

Tags: winapi, hid, raw-input

I trying to write program that is working properly with [GetRawInputBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputbuffer) API and consuming all input with little overhead on separate thread.

But I found that [WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input-device-change) messages get lost when reading [RAWINPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinput) via [GetRawInputBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputbuffer) instead of usual [WM_INPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input) approach.

[My code](https://github.com/DJm00n/RawInputDemo/blob/5016b75e64f5affc52a2309a4aa9c4c40e5bb65b/RawInputLib/RawInputDeviceManager.cpp#L70-L181) (I removed some error checking):

```cpp
void RawInputDeviceManager::RawInputManagerImpl::ThreadRun()
{
    // if I set it to true then WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE does not come
    constexpr bool buffered = false;

    // prepare buffer for up to 32 raw input messages
    m_InputDataBuffer.resize(std::max({ sizeof(RAWKEYBOARD), sizeof(RAWMOUSE), sizeof(RAWHID) }) * 32);

    m_WakeUpEvent = ::CreateEventExW(nullptr, nullptr, 0, EVENT_ALL_ACCESS);

    WNDCLASSEXW wc{};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Message";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) -> LRESULT
    {
        RawInputManagerImpl* manager = reinterpret_cast<RawInputManagerImpl*>(::GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, 0));

        if (manager)
        {
            switch (message)
            {
            case WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE:  // <== get lost after ::GetRawInputBuffer(..) call
            {
                manager->OnInputDeviceChange();
                return 0;
            }
            case WM_INPUT:
            {
                manager->OnInput(reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(lParam));
                return 0;
            }
            }
        }

        return ::DefWindowProcW(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    };
    wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(RawInputManagerImpl*); // add some space for this pointer
    wc.hInstance = ::GetModuleHandleW(nullptr);

    ATOM classAtom = ::RegisterClassExW(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = ::CreateWindowExW(0, reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(classAtom), nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, nullptr, wc.hInstance, 0);

    ::SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, 0, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(this));

    Register(hWnd);

    // enumerate devices before start
    OnInputDeviceChange();

    // main message loop
    while (m_Running)
    {
        MSG msg;

        if (buffered)
            OnInputBuffered();

        while (true)
        {
            bool haveMessage = false;

            if (buffered)
            {
                // retrieve any message but WM_INPUT
                haveMessage = ::PeekMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, WM_INPUT - 1, PM_REMOVE) ||
                    ::PeekMessageW(&msg, 0, WM_INPUT + 1, 0, PM_REMOVE);
            }
            else
            {
                // retrieve any message
                haveMessage = ::PeekMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
            }

            if (!haveMessage)
                break;

            // not needed since we are not interested in WM_CHAR or WM_DEADCHAR
            //::TranslateMessage(&msg);

            // dispatch message to WndProc
            ::DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }

        // wait for new messages
        ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, &m_WakeUpEvent, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS, MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);
    }

    Unregister();
    ::DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    ::UnregisterClassW(reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(classAtom), wc.hInstance);
}

bool RawInputDeviceManager::RawInputManagerImpl::Register(HWND hWnd)
{
    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[] =
    {
        // register for all HID device generic types (keyboard/mouse/joystick etc)
        {
            HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC,
            0,
            RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY | RIDEV_INPUTSINK | RIDEV_PAGEONLY,
            hWnd
        }
    };

    return ::RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, ARRAYSIZE(rid), sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));
}

void RawInputDeviceManager::RawInputManagerImpl::OnInputBuffered()
{
    // Processing all pending WM_INPUT messages in message queue
    while (true)
    {
        UINT size = static_cast<UINT>(m_InputDataBuffer.size());
        RAWINPUT* input = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(m_InputDataBuffer.data());

        UINT result = ::GetRawInputBuffer(input, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

        if (result == 0 || result == static_cast<UINT>(-1))
            return;

        // hack for a undefined QWORD used in NEXTRAWINPUTBLOCK macro
        using QWORD = __int64;

        for (; result; result--, input = NEXTRAWINPUTBLOCK(input))
        {
            OnInput(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this bug in Windows?

PS: This `WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE` event was added in Windows Vista and have proven that it [has some bugs in its implementation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110902-00/?p=9743).

PPS: As a workaround I can subscribe to [WM_DEVICECHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange) message via [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationw) but I not sure if I doing something wrong in this case.

Comment: Raymond Chen's blog entry doesn't claim or even hint that there were a bug in the implementation. It explains that the Windows Vista SDK had a bug in a macro definition. That macro is purely a helper, and there is nothing that keeps you from writing correct code, using the Windows Vista SDK or any later release.

Comment: @IInspectable You're right. But `GET_DEVICE_CHANGE_LPARAM` vs `GET_DEVICE_CHANGE_WPARAM` story showing that there are clearly some issues with code review at times when it was introduced...

Comment: @RemyLebeau m_InputDataBuffer is allocated on begining of listing `m_InputDataBuffer.resize(std::max({ sizeof(RAWKEYBOARD), sizeof(RAWMOUSE), sizeof(RAWHID) }) * 32);` and its used as out param in `GetRawInputBuffer()` call. Its declared as `std::vector<uint8_t> m_InputDataBuffer;`

Comment: @DJm00n sorry, I misread the code and thought `m_InputDataBuffer` was an array of pushed `RAWINPUT` structs discovered from processing the `WM_INPUT...` messages. In any case, is there a reason why you are using `std::max(...)` the way you are, instead of using `sizeof(RAWINPUT)`?  Your use of `std::max()` is not accounting for the fact that each input event will have its own `RAWINPUTHEADER`, so you are not actually allocating enough memory for 32 *complete* `RAWINPUT`s.

Comment: @RemyLebeau youre right. better to use `sizeof(RAWINPUT)`. Anyways issue is not here.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked for me. Could you provide more details to help us reproduce the problem?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo have you tried to change `buffered` to `true`? I doesnt have `WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE` after that.

Comment: `::MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, &m_WakeUpEvent, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS, MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);` this line causes WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE missing.(not signaled)